# Как в js изменить текст элементу и всем его дочерним элементам?

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку все слова на странице заменились на одно случайное слово из этих: "1","2","3". То есть каждое слово на странице должно замениться на одно случайное из этого списка

Comment: Покажите структуру HTML и уточните, что именно хотите сделать. Сейчас заголовок и описание расходятся. Да и элемент элементу рознь - есть span/li/ul/i/button/table - они могут не содержать текст, как таковой, поэтому список тегов для замены текста лучше уточнить. Так же тег может содержать текст и другие теги, а если сделать в лоб, то меняя содержимое первого тега на строку, дочерние пропадут ¯\\(ツ)/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта задача решается с помощью поиска на странице (или в элементе) всего текста. В HTML существует тип нод TEXT_NODE который и представляет из себя текстовые ноды для того чтобы их отыскать существует метод документа [createTreeWalker](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1573958/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-js-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc). Я не буду писать о том как привязать событие к кнопке или как сгенерировать число от 1 до 3 — это базовые вещи. Что касается простой демонстрации приведу такой скрипт:

```
const walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT)
while(walker.nextNode()) {
    walker.currentNode.data = walker.currentNode.data.replace(/\S+/g,  1)
}
```

Метод `nextNode` служит для перехода к следующей ноде иначе возвращает `null` поэтому его можно использовать в условии цикла. Для замены содержимого ноды используем свойство `data`. Далее используется регулярка `/\S+/g` — буквально обозначающая поиск всех (`g`) непрерывных непробельных последовательностей (таким образом выбираются русские слова и слова и числа на любых других языка кроме тех что пишуться латиницей)

Демонстрация для этой страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]